# Why can't I see user-added information with Django?

Tags: django, model

I'm using Django 2.2 and PostgreSQL. I want to display the product information that the user has added to the detail page. I see the information in the 'StoreOtherInfo' model, but I don't see the information in the 'Product' model. How can I do that?

store/models.py

```
class StoreOtherInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    neighborhood = models.CharField(max_length=11)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

products/models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    description = RichTextField()
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.seller
```

store/views.py

```
from store.models import StoreOtherInfo
from products.models import Product

def neighbor_detail(request,username):

    neighbor_detail = get_object_or_404(User,username = username)
    neighbor_list = StoreOtherInfo.objects.all()
    product_list = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'store/neighbor_detail.html', {'neighbor_detail':neighbor_detail, 'neighbor_list':neighbor_list, 'product_list':product_list})
```

templates/neighbor_detail.html

```
      <strong><p>{{neighbor_detail.first_name}} {{neighbor_detail.last_name}}</p></strong>
      <p>{{neighbor_detail.username}}</p>
      <p>{{neighbor_detail.email}}</p>
      <p>{{neighbor_detail.storeotherinfo.phone}}</p>
      <p>{{neighbor_detail.storeotherinfo.fax}}</p>
      <p>{{neighbor_detail.storeotherinfo.province}}</p>
      <p>{{neighbor_detail.storeotherinfo.district}}</p>
      <p>{{neighbor_detail.storeotherinfo.neighborhood}}</p>
      <p>{{neighbor_detail.product.product_name}}</p>
      <p>{{neighbor_detail.product.description}}</p>
      <p>{{neighbor_detail.product.added_date}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your Product model:

```
seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

the relation between User model and Product model is one-to-many. This means every User(in this case seller) can have multiple Products.
So when you try to access the Product objects of a User object as you did in you template: `<p>{{neighbor_detail.product.product_name}}</p>`  you end up giving an attribution error because `neighbor_detail.product` is not a single object of Product class it's a collection.
replace your template code with this and i hope you realize whats happening.

```
<strong><p>{{neighbor_detail.first_name}} {{neighbor_detail.last_name}}</p></strong>
<p>{{neighbor_detail.username}}</p>
<p>{{neighbor_detail.email}}</p>
<p>{{neighbor_detail.storeotherinfo.phone}}</p>
<p>{{neighbor_detail.storeotherinfo.fax}}</p>
<p>{{neighbor_detail.storeotherinfo.province}}</p>
<p>{{neighbor_detail.storeotherinfo.district}}</p>
<p>{{neighbor_detail.storeotherinfo.neighborhood}}</p>

{% for product in neighbor_detail.product_set.all %}
  {{product.product_name}}<br/>
  {{product.description}}<br/>
  {{product.added_date}}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

note that `product_set` is the default name that django associate with products related to each user.

Answer (score 0):

A `User` can have multiple `Product`s, so you can't do `neighbor_detail.product` because `product` isn't defined on a `User`. You need to loop through the list of products with `{% for product in neighbor_detail.product_set.all %}` and then you can display the properties of each `product`.

Read [this] for more information about one-to-many relationships.